# Read as need, how to read first 256 bytes from online large file without downloading?

Tags: c, winapi, file-io, webdav

I need to read just first 256 B from large file, from mapped WebDAV drive.

I open file with

```
h_second = CreateFileA(second_server, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);
```

but it first downloads whole file, and after that can I read it. And I want something, that downloads just a small part of file and I read that.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you try `fopen()` followed by `fread()`?

Comment: @alk: Those are C library functions. The Windows (MSVC) implementation of `fread` will call `CreateFileA` for you, so that wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: When i Call CreateFileA or fopen it downloads first whole file, and after that can I read using fread or ReadFile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebDAV is an extension to HTTP, and HTTP already has a [range request.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2)

Comment: how can I change that range? It's not matter of WebClient Service? beacause i am using net use for mapping drive..

Comment: I think the point MSalters is trying to make is that you would have to access the WebDAV server directly using HTTP, such as with the WinInet or WinHTTP API, instead of using a mapped drive.

Comment: Ok, thanks I did that using WinHTTP, Send request and recieve required 256 Bytes

Answer (score 1):

WebDAV is an extension to HTTP, and HTTP already has a range request.
I dont think it is important to solve this problem.

## include abc.def.c